# Get array from nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'd like to know if there's a way to extract values from objects in nested arrays, in some kind of combo with lodash's `get`:

```
const obj = { arr: [{ a: 2 },{ a: 3 }] };
get(obj, 'arr.a'); // [2, 3]
```

But it should still work for other uses:

```
const obj = { nestedObj: { a: 4 } };
get(obj, 'nestedObj.a'); // 4
```

It's some kind of advanced "get" that just works how you would expect it, if you forget about array and objects etc.

Comment: What is the benefit of including a library to do `get(obj, 'nestedObj.a');` when you can just do `obj.nestedObj.a` and get the same result?

Comment: @mwilson it could be useful in some cases, like have your object properties access in constants. like `const CAR_WHEELS= "car.parts.wheels"` you can do get(obj, CAR_WHEELS);

Comment: @mwilson `obj.a` will not work in first example.

Comment: @MaheerAli: Yes, that is correct. Because it's an array. You could still use `.filter` or `.find` or one of the many other array methods to search for the value you're after.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible using lodash, look up json path instead. The corresponding JSON path query would be `arr[*].a`. See a working example below, where I use [this](https://github.com/dchester/jsonpath) json path implementation. There are a few more implementations out there, choose the one that fits you the best.

```js
const obj = { arr: [{ a: 2 },{ a: 3 }] };
console.log(jsonpath.query(obj, "arr[*].a")); // [2, 3]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsonpath@1.0.1/jsonpath.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a recursive function that traverses the keys and extracts the values. If the type of the value is an array it uses `Array.map()` (might be `Array.flatMap()` to handle nested arrays) to iterate it.

```js
const getFn = (path, obj) => {
  const inner = ([key, ...path], obj) => {
    if(!path.length) return obj[key];

    return Array.isArray(obj[key]) ?
      obj[key].map(o => inner(path, o)) :
      inner(path, obj[key]);
  }
  
  return inner(path.split('.'), obj);
}
  


console.log(getFn('arr.a', { arr: [{ a: 2 },{ a: 3 }] }));
console.log(getFn('nestedObj.a', { nestedObj: { a: 4 } }));
console.log(getFn('arr.a.b', { arr: [{ a: [{ b: 1 }, { b: 2 }] },{ a: [{ b: 1 }, { b: 2 }] }] }));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a complete dynamic approach and look for the given keys and take the parts where a key matches.

The result is always an array.

If needed, you could add a check which pulls the only item and returns it.

```js
function getValues(object, path) {
    var [key, ...rest] = path.split('.');
    if (!rest.length && key in object) return [object[key]];
    return Object.entries(object).reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
        if (!v || typeof v !== 'object') return r;
        if (k === key) r.push(...getValues(v, rest.join('.')));
        r.push(...getValues(v, path));
        return r;
    }, []);
}


console.log(getValues({ arr: [{ a: 2 }, { a: 3 }] }, 'arr.a')); // [2, 3]
console.log(getValues({ nestedObj: { a: 4 } }, 'nestedObj.a')); // 4
```